# Remove an appended element on dialog box close

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I use JQuery and Ajax to update my database.
After each successful update, a png icon is displayed for 1 second.
To be more specific, the update form is contained into a JQuery dialog box.
The problem is that after updating, and closing the dialog box, the icon does not show again until I refresh the page.
I believe that I have to unbind after closing dialog box but I couldn't know how.
Below is my code

```
$(this).find('.mydialog').dialog({
width: 'auto',
height:'auto',
resizable: false,
buttons: function() {
        $(this).dialog("open");
    },
modal:true,
open: function() {
        $(this).find('.form1').on('submit', function() {
        var id = $(this).find('.ID').val(); 
        var name = $(this).find('.NAME').val(); 
        var dataString = 'id='+ id + '&name=' + name; 

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../myfolder/update.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(){ // the displayed icon
            $('.info').append("<img src='../images/success.png' width='30px' height='35' />").delay(1000).fadeOut();
            }
        });
            return false;           
    });
},

close: function() {
       $(this).dialog("destroy"); // I tried this but it doesn't work!      
},
});
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this line:

```
$('.info').append("<img src='../images/success.png' width='30px' height='35' />").delay(1000).fadeOut();
```

to

```
$('.info').show().html("<img src='../images/success.png' width='30px' height='35' />").delay(1000).fadeOut();
```

Comment: can you tell me how close the dialog box after updating?

Comment: I have make this [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uwaMAPU/2/edit) so you can see how it works all!

Comment: For close the dialog try this one: `$( this ).dialog( "close" );`

Comment: Interesting! You are so kind :)
But I have another issue, the dialog box doesn't want to be closed after updating, even when I used :
    $(this).dialog("close");

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately, but I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: There was a typo in the demo: [UPDATED](http://jsbin.com/OgUNuKu/2/edit) `beforeSend` was wrong

Comment: The beforeSend worked perfectally, but it is not the case for success